# Total no. of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in $x^2-y^2=2013$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Total no. of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ which satisfy $x^2-y^2=2013$

My try:: $(x-y).(x+y) = 3 \times 11 \times 61$

If we Calculate for positive integers Then $(x-y).(x+y)=1.2013 = 3 .671=11.183=61.33$

my question is there is any better method for solving the given question.

thanks

Comment: No, your method is good and very probably the simplest one.

Comment: The negatives should also be mentioned. The total number of ordered pairs, for an odd number $n$ with prime power factorization $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ is $2(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this pretty quickly, since you essentially need to solve a bunch of linear systems. One of them is e.g.

$$x-y = 3\times 11$$
$$x+y = 61$$

Just compute the inverse matrix of

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

and multiply that with the vectors corresponding to the different combinations of factors.

(ps. How do I write matrices???)

Comment: Some basic info on writing matrices is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023). (Re: ps. How do I write matrices???)

Comment: @MartinSleziak That MathJax basic tutorial page looks very handy! Bookmarked.